# React Module not found with Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I am working on an app that I started with create-react-app. I've included react-bootstrap and had everything working well. Then last night I tried to install [react-d3-component](https://github.com/codesuki/react-d3-components).

I followed the npm instructions:

- `npm install react-d3-components`
- `npm install & npm run build:js`

After running that the next time I tried `npm` start I got the following error with my Bootstrap:

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in '/home/nick/Desktop/crypto/src'
```

I have since tried uninstalling react-d3-components and uninstalling and reinstalling react-bootstrap to no avail. I imagine the problem is with `npm run build:js` and a Bootstrap extension but I'm not sure.

Any idea how to fix this?

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/crypto

Comment: Can you reproduce this error on codesandbox.io?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/crypto

Comment: A button on codesanbox popped up that said dependency not found install Bootstrap. I clicked it and now everything works on codesandbox, but when I try to npm install Bootstrap locally I'm getting the same module error I was before even after reinstalling Bootstrap.

Comment: Try deleting your node modules directory and then run `npm install`

Comment: Tried it and getting errors.

Comment: It looks like the Bootstrap issue is gone but now I'm having issues with node-sass not working.

Comment: I had to play around with getting everything set back up but your approach solved the Bootstrap issue. Thanks!